# How can I terminate an application using Python on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, exit

I have created a program and I want to make it exit Visual Studio Code once it is done with the program, how can I do that?

Comment: Is the VS Code process a parent of the Python process? Why do you want to close VS Code from Python?

Comment: Why do you need VS Code open to run your program? Can you just run it in the terminal?

Comment: I don't think you should do this, closing programs with Python is fairly easy, if you Google it you will find numerous ways to do this, however if you don't know how, then you should probably start with something easier, like bash. Though Python is powerful, it isn't designed to do administrative tasks, as simple tasks may require relatively complex solutions. To do system administration, PowerShell is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is

```
import os
os.system('pkill <vs process name>')
```

..but it looks kind of lame. Consider to run your application from cli:

```
python app.py
```

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would want to run such a simple command using `os.system()` instead of directly running it in bash.